# convert hex codes to characters PHP

Tags: php, hex, decode

Here are some examples: 
\x2f
\x3f
\x253d

Is there a PHP function that can convert these types of characters? I can't seem to find anything.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: `echo "\x3f";` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `hexdec()`. It should cover what you need.

[Here's the link to the PHP manual on the subject](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php)